# Gauss map and the Gaussian curvature

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, solution-verification, curves, surfaces

Consider a Gauss map $N$ on a surface $S$ with Gaussian curvature $K$ everywhere non-zero and with mean curvature $H=0$. The differential of the Gauss map satisfies
$$\tag{1}
\left(d N_s\right)^2=-K \operatorname{Id}_s.
$$
My lecture notes state that it follows from eq. $(1)$ that $\forall s\in S$ and all pairs of tangents $t_1,t_2\in T_s S$ we have that
$$\tag{2}
dN_s(t_1)\cdot dN_s(t_2)=-K(t_1\cdot t_2)
$$
Can someone explain how eq. $(2)$ follows from eq. $(1)$, because I do not see the connection.

**Edit:** I know that the differential of a Gauss map is self-adjoint. Rewriting eq. $(2)$ with bracket-notation, we then have
$$
\left\langle d N_s t_1, d N_s t_2\right\rangle=\left\langle d N_s d N_s t_1, t_2\right\rangle=\left\langle\left(d N_s\right)^2 t_1, t_2\right\rangle=-K\left\langle t_1, t_2\right\rangle
$$

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely right!

Comment: Great, thank you :)